# Adjective conjugation of 小さい and 少ない in these sentences

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations, adjectives, i-adjectives

I’ve come across some adjective conjugation that I don’t fully understand in two separate but related example sentences, and so my translations are definitely wonky.

飲んでいるでしょう。その証拠に、ぜんぜんお腹が小さくならないじゃない.

Translation: Probably drinking? As evidenced, never stomach (something not little)….?

I know 小さくない means ‘not a little’ but this ならない is confusing me, I only know it from　なければならない meaning 'must' but that' doesn't seem to apply here. The meaning overall is eluding me.

文法のルールが説明できるからと言って、それが上手に使えるとは限らない。その証拠に、実際に作文の宿題をチェックしたら、正しく書けていないことが少なくない。

Translation: Just because I’m able to explain the grammar rules doesn’t necessarily mean I’m good at using them. As shown, in reality when I check my homework essays I’m not able to correctly read *not a little*?

In this sentence, both the final verb and adjective are confusing me. 書けていない I think means ‘not being able to read’ whilst 少なくない means ‘not a little/not few’ but put them together and I’m lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us review the adjectives involved to make sure there is no confusion.

> ***Size vs. Quantity/Frequency:***

***Size:***

「[小]{ちい}さい」 = "small".

「[大]{おお}きい」 = "large"

***Quantity/Frequency:***

「[少]{すく}ない」 = "few", "a little", "not frequent"

「[多]{おお}い」 = "many", "much", "frequent"

> ***Moving on to Grammar:***

To express "to get or become (adjective)" in Japanese, you need to attach the verb 「なる」 to an adjective.  In doing so, however, you need to conjugate the adjective into its [連用形]{れんようけい}(conjunctive form).  Yes, just like verbs do, adjectives also conjugate in Japanese.

The 連用形 of 「小さ**い**」 is 「小さ**く**」.  Likewise, 「少な**い**」 to 「少な**く**」.

「小さくなる」 = "to get small(er)", "to shrink in size", etc.

「少なくなる」 = "to lessen in quantity", "to become less frequent", etc.

連用形 is extremely important.  If I, who is neither a teacher nor linguist, must use the word on a daily basis, that should tell you how important it is.

The plain negative form of an i-adjective is also formed with 連用形.　「小さ**い**」 becomes「小さ**く**ない」 and 「少な**い**」 becomes 「少な**く**ない」.  All humans live in the world of 連用形.  In Japan, even animals live in the world of 連用形.

> ***Finally, your sentences:***

「[飲]{の}んでいるでしょう。その[証拠]{しょうこ}に、ぜんぜんお[腹]{なか}が[小]{ちい}さくならないじゃない。」

"You must have been drinking (alcohol).  As evidence, your belly hasn't shrunk one bit!"

「その証拠に、[実際]{じっさい}に[作文]{さくぶん}の[宿題]{しゅくだい}をチェックしたら、[正]{ただ}しく[書]{か}けていないことが[少]{すく}なくない。」

I skipped the first sentence because your translation of that is good.

"As evidence, when I actually checked my composition homework, (I found that) there are quite a few things that have not been written correctly."

「正しく書けていない」 literally means "has/have not been written correctly".  For a translation purpose, one could use "I have not written (or even 'did not write') correctly."

「少なくない」, which expresses high quantity/frequency, is one of those phrases that we native speakers use far more often than Japanese-learners do.  It means 「多い」, which is what the learners tend to use.

Answer (score 0):

Adverb+なる means "to become", as in 学生{がくせい}になる (to become a student), 綺麗{きれい}になる (to become clean/pretty), or 大{おお}きくなる (to become big), so in the first sentence, 小{ちい}さくならない means "not to become small". In the second sentence, 少{すく}なくない is just the negative of 少{すく}ない, so it means "not a few" (*i.e.*, many).

The first sentence is difficult to make sense of without context, but translated literally it could mean "(I/you/he/etc.) probably drinks (a lot/regularly). Doesn't that mean (my/your/his/etc.) stomach will remain large (not become small)?"

The second one is easier: 書{か}く means to write (not to read ;) ), so 書{か}けないこと means "things I can't write". So the sentence means "There are many things I can't write correctly."